# Creating hovercard/tooltip

Tags: jquery, html, css, ajax

I'm trying to create a hovercard for a social network project. The idea is that when you hover over some user's name, a HC will appear containing some more info about that user. When you move your mouse away, it will disappear after 2 seconds.

Here's my code. First, I have an empty div with a class of `hov` that will contain the info.

```
<div class="hov">

</div>
```

Here's my jquery script:

```
$(function(){

    $('body').on('mouseenter', 'a', function(){

        let username = $(this).attr('href');
        let quotesname = JSON.stringify(username);
        let name = JSON.parse(quotesname)

        // on the live site this span is populated by an Ajax call
        data = "foo";
        $(".hov").html("<span>" + data + "</span>");

        $(this).focus().addClass('hov');

    }).on('mouseleave', 'a', function(){

        setTimeout(function(){

            $(".hov").hide();

        }, 2000);                           
    });
});
```

(All of the above is in the header file, which is included in all other files)

And finally, here's the CSS:

```
.hov {

  position: relative;

 }

.hov span {

  display: none; 
  height: 150px;
  width: 250px;
  white-space: nowrap;
}

.hov:focus span {

  display:block;
  position:absolute;
  padding: 0.2em 0.6em;
  border:1px solid #996633;
  border-radius: 5px;
  background-color: grey !important;
  color:#fff;
  z-index: 100;
}
```

My idea was to detect using jquery when someone is hovering over a link. Then it would extract the `href` part and send it to the php response file, which would check if the `href` part matches any of the usernames in the database. If it does, it would send the info about that user that would be displayed in the HC (if a link contains a user's name, it's always the link to that user's profile). If it doesn't, it won't send anything and then no HC will be displayed (that's why I used the `if(data)` condition inside the ajax part). I managed to make the HC appear when you hover over a username, along with the info sent from the php response file; however I face two problems that I can't solve, no matter how hard I try.

1) When I remove the mouse from the link, the HC disappears, but so does the link I hovered over (no matter if it's a text, picture..whatever it was, it's gone). I tried all sorts of things in the `mouseleave` part (detect if the div is not in focus, remove or detach the div, remove the class, remove the class attribute from the `hov`, etc), but with no result. That's why I have that line `$(".hov").hide();` there, it's the best I could get so far. I suspect that it has something with removing the `hov` class completely when you move your mouse away, I really can't tell.

2) I'm not sure how to apply the `hov` styling only when I hover over a link to a user's profile, and not some random link. I created the ajax call for that very purpose, to see if a link is to a user or not, but I'm not sure if and how I can use the same logic to solve this.

Any help would be much appreciated,

Thanks!

Comment: Can you get rid of the PHP from this? It seems like a strictly JavaScript/CSS question.

Comment: @miken32 OK, will do that

Comment: In your event code just have it create the `<span>` with some fixed text. This will allow others to recreate the code more easily. See more details about a [mcve].

Comment: Sorry. Been very busy, completely forgot about this. Yes, your answer led me in the right direction. I finally managed to create what I intended. Thanks, miken.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> When I remove the mouse from the link, the HC disappears, but so does the link I hovered over

Your event listener is looking for mouseenter on an `a` element. Within that listener you run this code:

```
$(this).focus().addClass('hov');
```

Which gives the `a` element (`this`) the `hov` class. Then, in the mouseleave code, you say this:

```
$(".hov").hide();
```

Therefore, you're hiding the `a` element.

> I'm not sure how to apply the hov styling only when I hover over a link to a user's profile, and not some random link

Use a distinct class on the link and then style that class.

---

Try something like this (see comments inline):

```js
$(function(){
    // apply the event listener directly to the element
    // note we've given the element a class
    $('a.student')
    .on('mouseenter', function(){
        data = "foo";
        // you have to show the tooltip element
        $(".hov").html("<span>" + data + "</span>").show();
    })
    .on('mouseleave', function(){
        setTimeout(function(){
            // hide the tooltip element after a couple of seconds
            $(".hov").hide();
        }, 2000);                           
    });
});
```

```css
.hov {
  /* ensure this is hidden at startup */
  display: none;
  position: relative;
 }

.hov span {
  height: 150px;
  width: 250px;
  white-space: nowrap;
  /* if the parent div is hidden, so is this, no need to set display property on it */
  display:block;
  position:absolute;
  padding: 0.2em 0.6em;
  border:1px solid #996633;
  border-radius: 5px;
  background-color: grey !important;
  color:#fff;
  z-index: 100;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="hov">

</div>

<p>
    <a class="student">A link!</a>
</p>
```